# Why can't I change target framework in vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, frameworks, target

I'm trying to upgrade an old vs 2003 project and install it on a newer server, windows 2008 (maybe r2, don't know) which seems to have frameworks 2.0, 3 and 3.5. I did this upgrade by opening the project in vs2010 and letting it upgrade it for me. When trying to install it on this new server it says I need framework 4 and I don't understand why? Project -> properties -> compile -> advanced compile options, target framework shows 2.0. Shouldn't this mean only 2.0 should be needed on machine it will be installed in?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you installing the solution or the binaries on the new server? It's not clear from your question?

Comment: Sorry, binaries is what I'm trying to install I guess. An msi-package that this project creates and should install a windows service on this server.

Comment: Just to be sure? Is the MSI package compile with the correct framework too?

Comment: Thank you very much! You just solved my problem. Setup project dependency was set to 4.0, changed that to 2.0 and it works fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that all aspects of the code including installer target the right framework.